# First time using Malloc, and program crashes

Tags: c, malloc

the program is intended to recieve 'n' number of students and their names and sort them 
(havent got to the sorting part).
I cant figure out why my program crashes when i test it.
this is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MaxNameLen 100
int main() {

    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    char *names;
    char **pointerToNames = (char **) malloc(n * sizeof(char));
    if (pointerToNames == NULL)
        return 0;

    int i;

    for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        names = (char *) malloc(MaxNameLen);
        gets(names);
        pointerToNames[i] = names;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        free(pointerToNames[i]);
        free(names);
    }
}
```

Comment: @haccks http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/gets/

Comment: @Inisheer; Sorry! `gets` become history now in C.

Answer (score 5):

You have three problems. The first is that you don't allocate enough entries for the "array":

```
malloc(n * sizeof(char))
```

Should be

```
malloc(n * sizeof(char*))
```

The second problem is the reading loop:

```
for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
```

Here the loop condition will cause you to loop one time to many, causing you to write beyond what you allocate (if you fix the first problem). The condition in the loop should be `i < n` like in the next loop.

The third problem is that you free the last string repeatedly in the loop

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    free(pointerToNames[i]);
    free(names);
}
```

As you assign `names` to `pointerToNames[i]` in the loop above, when that loop is done `names` will point to the last string you read, so `names` and `pointerToNames[n - 1]` will point to the same string.

---

Two other problems include that you are not freeing the actual `pointerToNames` memory you first allocate. And that you should not use `gets` (it has long been deprecated, and even removed in the latest standard). Use [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) (or [`gets_s`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/gets)) instead.

Also, [don't cast the return of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/440558).

Answer (score 1):

Your first `malloc` is meant to allocate memory for `N` pointers to chars, but you are allocating `N` chars, which is probably much less memory.

Change this line:

```
char **pointerToNames = (char **) malloc(n * sizeof(char));
```

To this:

```
char **pointerToNames = malloc(n * sizeof(*pointerToNames));
```

Besides:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        free(pointerToNames[i]);
        free(names);
```

This frees memory for the indicated index, but you also free `names`, which happened to be the temporary pointer you used to allocate memory, and then you assigned the current value of `name` to each eement. So, there is no need to free `names`.

Maybe you find simpler to change your second part (the code that allocates memory for each element of your array) to this:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        pointerToNames[i] = malloc(MaxNameLen);
        if (pointerToNames[i])
          fgets(pointerToNames[i], MaxNameLen-1, stdin);
    }
```

So `names` is no longer used and instead of `gets()`, use `fgets()`. Note that the `for` loop goes from `0` to `N-1`, not to `N`. `pointerToNames[N]` is not a valid array element.